# Authenticated file encryption scheme

Tags: authenticated-encryption

Suppose I want to encrypt and authenticate a large file.  The file is so large that it cannot fit entirely in memory, and I will be processing it in a streaming fashion.  Truncation of the file and forgeries must be detected, but it is okay to if it is not detected until after all data so far has been processed.

My current plan is to encrypt the file in chunks.  Each chunk is of a fixed size, and generates an authentication tag $T$.  I don't release $T$ directly.  Instead, I have a state $S$ (initialized to some arbitrary value).  At each step, I execute $S := \mathop{PRF}(N || S || T)$.  Here $\mathop{PRF}$ is an arbitrary PRF, such as keyed Blake2b or HMAC; the details are not important.  $N$ is a chunk counter.  Each $S$ is emitted to the output stream immediately upon computation.

Truncation attacks are detected by ~~including the number of chunks to be transmitted as the first bytes of the first chunk~~ having the last chunk have a flag set.

Decryption works as usual.  Each tag is used to compute the corresponding $S$, which is checked against the transmitted values.  If at any point the two don't match, then a forgery error is reported.

I need to be able to authenticate incrementally.  The input might be an infinite stream.

Does this provide $\text{IND-CPA}$ and $\text{INT-CTXT}$?

Comment: Do you have a question? ​ (In any case, do you have some reason for preferring your idea over encrypt-then-HMAC with an underlying encryption scheme for which encryption and decryption both allow streaming?) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I want to be able to authenticate incrementally.  Consider the case where the data is actually an infinite stream that is produced over time.

Comment: In light of ​ "it is okay to if it is not detected until after all data so far has been processed" , ​ I think that should go into your post too. ​ ​ ​ ​